# Login button shows briefly in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a small issue with my login button showing in between being logged in and being on the login view. below is my link:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info navbar-btn" href="login" ng-if="currentPath !== '/login'" ng-show="!user" ng-cloak>Login</a>
```

What happens is when the user logs out for a brief second the user object is empty and they are on a different view i.e. /posts the Login button will show until the page redirects to the login view then it disappears like it is supposed to. I am trying to figure out a way to remove the brief display.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: do you use ui-router ? because there is a better way to achieve this ng-if="currentPath !== '/login'"

Comment: yes please tell me how

Comment: add `ng-hide` class to element so it would be initially hidden?

Comment: ng-if="currentPath !== '/login'" ng-show="!user"  why do you have ng-if and ng-show together ?

Comment: you can write in one expression in ng-if  ;)

Comment: @MayK because the button only shows if the user is not logged in but I also did not want to show the button if the are already on the login view

Comment: ng-if="!$state.includes('login') || user"

Comment: @MayK that worked! thx, except I went back to my original. ng-if="currentPath !== '/login' || !user". make it an answer and I will uptick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume your state name is 'login', this is how you would do it:

```
<div ng-if="!$state.includes('login')></div>
```

and don't forget to add this to your controller:

```
    controller: function($scope,$state) {
        $scope.$state = $state;


    }
```

Comment: here is what my route currently looks like. `.when('/login', {
                title: 'Login',
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })`

Comment: so you are not using ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are willing to go ui-router way, you will need to modify the way you deleting the `user` object. So, when logout is initiated do not delete `user`, delete `user` once promise is resolved upon server OK and then you redirect.